# Typo3 Simple Template for BackendLayout

Tags: typescript, templates, typo3

I am programming on a new Site with Typo3 and I am using BackendLayouts for the style, but it shows just the Main-Content (number 0). I don't understand the docs to include the BackendLayout in my template. Does someone have a simple solution for a beginner?
My current template:

```
page = PAGE
page {
  10 = TEXT
}
```

Doesn't show me anything:

```
page = PAGE
page {
  10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You could start reading this tutorial: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/main/en-us/Preface/Index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to evaluate the settings and select a proper template.

after configuration and selecting of page layouts you can use the value of the page layout which can be easily injected from typoscript to your fluid templates to select an appropriate partial and get that layout you intended.

```
page {
  10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
  10 {
    :
    variables {
      :
      pagelayout = TEXT
      pagelayout {
        data = pagelayout
        ifEmpty = default
        replacement {
          10 {
            search = pagets__
            replace =
          }
        }
      :
    }
  }
}
```

otherwise you can select different templates based on the page layout:

```
page = PAGE
page {
  :
  10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
  10 {
    templateName = TEXT 
    templateName {
      cObject = TEXT
      cObject {
        data = pagelayout
        ifEmpty = Default
        case = uppercamelcase
        required = 1
        split {
          token = pagets__
          cObjNum = 1
          1.current = 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```